# JavaScript. Как обойти ограничение в 16 разрядов в числовом типе данных?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Мне на `NodeJs` по `http` приходят числовые данные, их нужно складывать в базу.

Проблема в том что в одной из таблиц есть поле типа `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, то есть 64 битное и все биты под значение.

В `JavaScript` числа тоже 64 битные но под значение отводится 52 бита (остальные биты это мантиса и знак) если приходит число больше чем на 52 бита - младшие биты отбрасываются без ошибки в интерпретаторе.

Получается что клиенты мне шлют одни числа а в базе видят другие. Можно ли как то обойти это ограничение?

Comment: как вариант отправлять числа в виде строк

Comment: так сейчас и обходим ограничение, но это же костылик. Я ж всех не заставлю слать строки когда в базе числовое значение

Comment: А как они их шлют?

Comment: `http` пакетом, `post` или `put` или `patch` в зависимости от контекста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения этой проблемы можно использовать модули:

- [node-bignum - Big integers for Node.js using OpenSSL](https://github.com/justmoon/node-bignum)
- [node-bigint - Arithmetic on big integers using libgmp](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint)
- [node-int64 - Support for representing 64-bit integers in JavaScript](https://github.com/broofa/node-int64)

Comment: Спасибо, поизучаю. Технически это наверно ответ на вопрос... Но хотелось бы понять не "чем" а "как" решить эту задачу. А то у меня складывается впечатление что мы на фронте не программируем а комбинируем.